# pm2 json file format for python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pm2

I have a command to execute  `python manage.py runserver 0:8000 --insecure`
using PM2 on a server.I'm unable to create the JSON file format so that i can run using that json file in place of writing the entire command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ecosystem.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
     script: 'manage.py',
     args: 'runserver 0:8000 --insecure'
  }]
}
```

Then:

```
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js
```

Comment: I have to create a file with name ecosystem.config.js   ?? And put the below data inside it . Right?

Comment: yes create the ecosystem.config.js in the same folder than you app and put this into it More info: https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/reference/ecosystem-file/